# Jquery multiple button press submits ajax multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form, that allows admin personal to edit or "delete" an item from inventory.  The item isn't actually removed from the inventory just removes it from the active inventory.  When the user presses the "Delete" button a Bootstrap "alert" box appears and wants to verify the action of removing from active inventory.  The box has two buttons "Delete" and "Keep".  Clicking either hides the confirmation box.  If the user clicked "Delete" the code works as it's supposed too, if however the user clicks "Keep" and then later decides to attempt to "Delete" again showing the alert box and confirming "Delete" the ajax form is then submitted as many times as the "Keep" and "Delete" buttons in the confirmation box are pressed, and the code breaks giving unwanted results. Unwanted results are: The phrase "Database error, XX-XX.XX.XX-XX has NOT been updated." the number of times "Keep" was pressed, followed by "XX-XX.XX.XX-XX was successfully removed from the active inventory". The modal background does not disappear and on occasion a non-dismissible modal appears. The only way to continue is to refresh the page. However the item IS "removed" and the database IS updated.

```
$('#myModal')
.on('click', 'button[name="del_but"]', function () {
    var ref = $(this).val();
    $('.del_bx').show('slow');
    $('#save').prop('disabled', true);
    $('.del_bx').on('click', '.btn', function () {
        var clkd = $(this).text();
        $('#save').prop('disabled', false);
        $('.del_bx').hide('slow');
        if (clkd === "Remove") {
            $.ajax({
                type: $('#group')
                    .attr('method'),
                url: "update.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: $('#group')
                    .serialize() + '&update=del&id=' + ref,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".loading")
                        .css("display", "block");
                    $(".btn")
                        .prop('disabled', true);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $(".loading")
                        .hide();
                    $(".btn")
                        .prop('disabled', false);
                }
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                var phrase;
                if (data === 1) {
                    phrase = '<p class="success_mod" style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold; font-size:1em; text-align:center;">' + ref + ' has been successfully removed from the active inventory.</p>';
                } else if (data === 2) {
                    phrase = '<p class="success_mod" style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold; font-size:1em; text-align:center;">You are not authorized!</p>';
                } else {
                    phrase = '<p class="success_mod" style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold; font-size:1em; text-align:center;">Database error, ' + ref + ' has NOT been updated.</p>';
                }
                $('.modal-header ul.nav-tabs').fadeOut(2000);
                $('.modal-body .tab-content').fadeOut(2000);
                $('.modal-footer').fadeOut(2000);
                $(phrase).insertAfter('#myModal .modal-body img');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
                    update_inv("in");
                }, 3000);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".success_mod").remove();
                }, 6000);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and the html

```
<form id="group" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        ...form stuff here...
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="save"></label>
            <div class="controls" style="text-align:center;"><br>
                <button type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="AR-02.09.16-00" class="btn btn-keep">Save</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                <button type="button" id="del_but" name="del_but" class="btn btn-success" value="AR-02.09.16-00">Delete</button>
                <div class="alert alert-danger fade in del_bx" role="alert">
                    <div style="text-align:left;">
                        <strong>Confirmation Needed!</strong>
                    </div>
                    <p style="font-size:1em; text-align: center;">Remove AR-02.09.16-00 from the active Rolling Stock?<br>Click REMOVE<br>or<br>KEEP Active.</p>
                    <div style="text-align:left;">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Remove</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-keep btn-sm">Keep</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You register the *del_bx* click handler inside your *$('#myModal')* click handler. This effectively registers an additional click handler whenever *#myModal* is clicked, and all of these handlers are called when *del_bx* is clicked.

Move the *$('.del_bx').on()* click handler registration outside of the *$('#myModal').on()* click handler registration.

Comment: @Bill please consider accepting answer if it helped to you.